# Error Starting Apache Storm Supervisor

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am trying to restart an Apache Storm cluster and I am running into some issues.  I have two supervisors that will not restart.  When I look at the supervisor logs, I see the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
  at backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultSerializationDelegate.deserialize(DefaultSerializationDelegate.java:56) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:89) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.deserializeLatestVersion(LocalState.java:65) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.snapshot(LocalState.java:47) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.get(LocalState.java:72) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$read_worker_heartbeat.invoke.(supervisor.clj:96) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$read_worker_heartbeats$iter__3992__3996$fn__3997.invoke(supervisor.clj:109) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:60) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at clojure.core$dorun.invoke(core.clj:2780) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at clojure.core$doall.invoke(core.clj:2796) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$read_worker_heartbeats.invoke(supervisor.clj:108) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$read_allocated_workers.invoke(supervisor.clj:125) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$sync_processes.invoke(supervisor.clj:230) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at clojure.lang.Afn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at clojure.core$partial$fn__4190.doInvoke(core.clj:2396) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__2467.invoke(event.clj:40) ~[storm-core-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]
  at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:853) [na:1.7.0]
Caused by java.io.StreamCorruptedExceptionL invalid stream header: 00000000
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:885)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
  at backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultSerializationDelegate.deserialized(DefaultSerializationDelegate.java:51)
  ... 23 common frames omitted
2015-04-29T10:36:34.096+0000 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Error when processing an event")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error when processing an event")
  at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:325)
  at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423)
  at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__2467.invoke(event.clj:48)
  at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:853)
```

I am guessing that this error has to do with data that was assigned to the supervisor that is corrupt now.  What is the best way to handle corrupt data?  I am new to Storm and know only basic info about it.

Storm 0.9.3
Java - IBM J9 VM (build 2.7, JRE 1.7.0 Linux PPC64-64)

Answer (score 3):

So there were files under the worker directory.  These files were corrupt and I had to delete everything that was under the workers directory.  I then restarted the supervisor and this started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little more info.

In your `conf/storm.yaml` you will have the location of your `storm.local.dir`. For me it is set to `/var/storm`. Inside this dir you will find worker heartbeats, the storm dist files...

Try stopping your storm supervisor, removing all data in the `workers` dir, and restarting the supervisor again. If this dosnt help try removing all files in the `storm.local.dir` instead.